# If String Is Contained By Brackets, Remove Them

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a function that will take input, check to see if it has "[" as the first char and "]" as the last and remove them if it does. The string may have more brackets in them, if that's the case then I need to print an error statement. Everywhere I've looked, I've seen examples of how to do this if it were just the two brackets, but I need to check if there are any more as well, and that's where I'm getting confused.

I've seen examples of using `regex`, and I know that if I can find a string with just the two brackets on the outside, I can use `substring` to trim it, but I can't figure out how to check the string for the instances of brackets without remvoing all of them.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `String` has a number of useful methods for checking its contents.

Comment: You could use `substring` to trim the outside brackets and then check if the trimmed string `contains` any brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(str.chatAt(0) == '[' && str.charAt(str.length()-1) == ']') //str.matches("\\[.*\\]")
{
    str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
}
if(str.contains("[") || str.contains("]")) //str.matches(".*[\\[\\]].*")
{
    //throw your error
}
```

Posted potential regex solutions beside the if statements. Warning: Not the greatest at regex, so they may not be correct.

as @Ingo pointed out in the comments, `str.charAt(0)` will fail on empty string.

Comment: Fails for the empty String.

Comment: @Ingo Yes, added that to the answer. The regex version should be fine I think though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.charAt(int) for do it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

Since you claim to know what you are doing to trim the leading and trailing brackets, it sounds like the missing link is the `.contains()` method on the `String` class.

```
if (myString.contains("]") || myString.contains("["))
    throw new Exception("myString contains invalid brackets");
```